# Change Internet Explorer security settings for trusted domains using Powershell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, trusted-sites

I was wondering if it is at all possible to make the following changes for trusted domains in Internet Explorer with PowerShell.

**Internet Explorer settings I wish to change:**

- Add http://website.com/ as a trusted site
- Allow ActiveX Filtering = Enable
- Allow previously unused ActiveX controls to run without prompt = Enable
- Allow Scriptlets = Enable
- Automatic Prompting for ActiveX controls = Disable
- Binary and script behaviours = Enable
- Display video and animation on a webpage that does not use external media player = Enable
- Download signed ActiveX controls = Enable
- Download unsigned ActiveX controls = Enable
- Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting = Enable
- Only allow approved domains to use ActiveX without prompt = Disable
- Run ActiveX controls and plugins = Enable
- Script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting = Enable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that it was!

Here's what i did: (Run powershell as an Administrator)

```
#Setting IExplorer settings
Write-Verbose "Now configuring IE"
#Add http://website.com as a trusted Site/Domain
#Navigate to the domains folder in the registry
set-location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set-location ZoneMap\Domains

#Create a new folder with the website name
new-item website/ -Force
set-location website/
new-itemproperty . -Name * -Value 2 -Type DWORD -Force
new-itemproperty . -Name http -Value 2 -Type DWORD -Force
new-itemproperty . -Name https -Value 2 -Type DWORD -Force

#Navigate to the trusted domains folder in the registry:

#Go to registry folder for Trusted Domains
#Zone 2 in this case resembles the trusted domains (Or zones if you'd prefer)
Set-Location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\zones\2"
```

Now you have all your settings pointed out as values. The trick is to find the proper values per setting.
In my case I found the values on:
http://support.microsoft.com/KB/182569 (A bit midway on the page)

Now we need to know what the preferred values are.
In my case I found that value 0 is Enabled, 1 is Disabled and 3 is (if supported) prompting.

Next off it's pretty simple.

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Allow ActiveX Filtering = Enable (2702)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 2702 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Allow previously unused ActiveX controls to run without prompt = Enable (1208)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 1208 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Allow Scriptlets = Enable (1208)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 1209 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls = Disable (2201)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 2201 -Value 3 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Binary and script behaviors = Enable (2000)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 2000 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-Display video and animation on a webpage that does not use external media player = Enable (120A)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 120A -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Download signed ActiveX controls = Enable (1001)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 1001 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Download unsigned ActiveX controls = Enable (1004)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 1004 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting = Enable (1201)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 1201 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-Only allow approved domains to use ActiveX without prompt = Disable (120B)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 120B -Value 3 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins = Enable (1200)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 1200 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force
```

-ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Script ActiveX controls marked as safe for scripting = Enable (1405)

```
new-itemproperty . -Name 1405 -Value 0 -Type DWORD -Force


cls #Clear the screen
cd C:\Windows\System32 #Go back to default folder
```

Answer (score 0):

For -ActiveX controls and plug-ins: Download unsigned ActiveX controls = Enable (1004) option,the action type was
0 permitted
1 prompt
3 prohibits